# Audio broken on clean install of ThinkPad T60

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, audio, thinkpad

I just reinstalled a clean version of XP SP3 on a ThinkPad T60. After downloading all of the missing drivers from the Lenovo site, everything seems to work except for the audio.

I installed the audio driver from http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/MIGR-62928.html (version 5.10.1.4326) so SoundMAX shows up in the control panel and everything in the Sound preferences looks okay, but no sound comes out of the speakers when I try to play music or hear the interface sound effects. There's also no sound if I plug in headphones and listen.

Some forums suggested installing [hotfix Q888111](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/888111) for the UAA Bus Driver but it's already included in SP3 so I can't install it. I also tried reinstalling the audio driver mentioned above in case something went wrong the first time, but it still doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to make the sound work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the ThinkPad has a hardware sound mixer which I didn't know (it's not actually my computer). Even though the volume was turned up in Windows, it wasn't on the hardware mixer.

All I needed to do was turn up the volume using the silver hardware volume buttons on the computer, then it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the ThinkVantage system update, see if it finds anything you need.

http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/tvsu-update.html

Comment: Right, forgot to mention that. It says that there are no available updates (which is strange, because I didn't install all of the software from the drivers page, especially not the ThinkVantage-branded things).

Comment: I wonder if it is missing the Microsoft UAA driver, you may have to uninstall the sound driver before you install this, then reinstall audio driver....http://www.techspot.com/drivers/driver/file/information/9662/